# Recursion virgin getting stack overflow error with collision detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics, collision, game-physics

I have a ball class that has position, velocity, and acceleration vectors as attributes. My program instantiates two ball objects and moves them around according to a gravitational force between them.

I have everything working great, but am trying to implement a collision detection feature that makes the balls bounce off of one another.

Here is the method that updates the velocity:

```
    public Chaney2DVector collisionVelocity(Ball ball2)
{
    float x = velocity.x + ((ball2.mass / mass) * (ball2.velocity.x - 
            ball2.collisionVelocity(this).x));
    float y = velocity.y + ((ball2.mass / mass) * (ball2.velocity.y - 
            ball2.collisionVelocity(this).y));
    Chaney2DVector updatedVelocity = new Chaney2DVector(x,y);
    velocity = updatedVelocity;
    return velocity;

}
```

I've used a method called recursion, haven't I? This is my first time trying to do this, so apologies if I've done something wrong.

When my program runs, I have this collision condition active in my update method:

```
    if (this.getDistance(ball2) < (this.radius + ball2.radius))
    {
        velocity = this.setVelocity(collisionVelocity(ball2).x,
                collisionVelocity(ball2).y);
    }
```

I want this program to assign the new collision velocity to the velocity variable in each ball. When I run the program, the balls move toward each other just fine. However, when the balls collide they don't bounce... they stick together in a stationary position and I get a stack overflow error. I read elsewhere that this may have something to do with a termination condition, but I have no idea what that means. Any ideas??

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The first rule of recursion is (not "don't talk about recursion") always have a terminating condition. You just call the same method until you get a `StackOverflowError`. You need some condition under which you call something else.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So what would a terminating condition look like in my case? Sorry for the ignorance, but an example would be super cool.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/). Notice how all the examples have a condition under which they return a value rather than a recursive call.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I looked at your link (thanks, btw!) and get what you mean about terminating condition (I think). What I don't understand is how to get my function to terminate. I tried using n=0, while (n=0), and n++ to make it calculate once, but I feel like I completely missed the point that the condition is used to control how many times the recursive function digs inside of itself. I'm stuck and a little frustrated so I apologize if this doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple example of recursion without terminating condition. This example will not find any end. Java will call the method, which causes java to call the method again. A neverending story:

```
public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursionWithoutTerminatingCondition();
    }

    private static void recursionWithoutTerminatingCondition() {
        recursionWithoutTerminatingCondition();
    }

}
```

This other example is much better. Java will start calling the method on and on, but reduces the parameter value for each call. This will lead to an ending:

```
public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursionWithTerminatingCondition(20);
    }

    private static void recursionWithTerminatingCondition(int numberOfTimes) {
        if (numberOfTimes > 0)
            recursionWithTerminatingCondition(numberOfTimes - 1);
    }

}
```

---

To your specific case:

- If you declare, that the collision velocity of one ball depends on the collision velocity of the other one, than java cannot find a solution.

Some common ways of building workarounds for that kind of problems:

- If you declare, that the collision velocity of one ball depends on the other ball's collision velocity **of the last time interval** (so a stored value of the last calculation), than java can calculate your values.
- Alternatively you could also let java calculate the collision velocity of the first ball, **assumpting that the other collision velocity is 0**. And than use that calculated collision velocity to calculate the other ball's collision velocity, and so on. You could than declare, that java can stop recalculating values, as soon as each recalculation is resulting in a change of less than 0.01 (or similar).
- Or maybe there is some other formula, that is not depending on the other balls collision velocity.

Sadly my physic knowledge is too short to help you with your formulas :(

Comment: Well, the collisionVelocity is a vector object that I created that basically just has an x and a y component. I'm trying to make it so that the balls will be moving around at whatever direction, and if they collide the velocities of each ball will be refreshed one time according to the calculation. The problem that I'm running into is that according to the physics I'm using (the fact that overall momentum within a system is conserved) the new velocities of each ball depends on the new velocities of the other. So I don't know how to make it send each on their own merry way. Make sense?